# Gitlab REST API Returning Different Values in Browser than Script

Tags: rest, gitlab

I am trying to write a python script to automate the retrieval of project data from Gitlab. However, I have encountered a situation where the results from the REST call are different when I access it from a browser than when I access it via my script.

For instance, going to `[local gitlab repo]/api/v4/projects` in chrome, I get a very long list of projects.

When I execute this sample python code,

```
url = "[local gitlab repo]/api/v4/projects"

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = get_credentials()

default_headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"}

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
response = session.request(method="GET", url=url, headers=default_headers, verify=False)
response.encoding = "utf-8"
response.raise_for_status()
    
print(json.loads(response.content))
```

the results that I get are quite different. It's a completely different list of projects, with no overlap with the projects returned in the browser.

I have tried the python code with both my username and password (using the `get_credentials()` call), and using a security token from gitlab. Specifically, I went to a project that I'm specifically interested in getting data for, and generated a Project Access Token and used that in my python script instead; it did not produce any different results.

Another thought was that the script credentials were failing in some way and the list it was getting was only those projects that were publicly available; that is not the case. I don't believe we have any publicly available projects - and when I try to access the REST API from the browser without having logged in, I get back an empty set of projects.

At this point I've exhausted my understanding of REST APIs or ways of debugging them. I have used the sample code above for other REST APIs (Jira, Jenkins, SonarQube, etc.) and it has worked fine (and consistently produced the same results as the browser). Any suggestion on how to proceed with debugging this are appreciated. Thanks!

In case it is pertinent, we are using Gitlab Enterprise Edition 15.7.3-ee.

Comment: Please note [this list of existing API clients](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/marketing/digital-experience/buyer-experience/-/merge_requests/1631/diffs#diff-content-84af7726633769130066b59433ae23f9f22bef6b). They're not officially listed on GitLab's homepage anymore, but hopefully still useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your default headers add Bearer before the the token. For example:
default_headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer access_token'}